# UseState Updated the hooks on 2nd time with the older value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am trying to update the hooks but its gets update on the second click with the older value, can anyone tell me where am I going wrong.

```
import { useFormik } from "formik";

const validateEmployee = (empData) => {
  const errors = {};
  if (!empData.EmailId) {
    errors.EmailId = "Please Enter Email ID";
  } else if (
    !/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(empData.EmailId)
  ) {
    errors.EmailId = "Invalid email address";
  }
  return errors;
};

const ForgotPassowrd = () => {
  const [FormObject, setFormObject] = useState({});
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      EmailId: "",
    },
    validate: validateEmployee,
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      setFormObject(formik.values);
      alert(JSON.stringify(values));
      console.log(FormObject);
    },
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>New Employee Form...</h2>

      <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
        <p>
          <label htmlFor="EmailId">Employee Email ID : </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="EmailId"
            value={formik.values.EmailId}
            onChange={formik.handleChange}
            onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
          ></input>
          {formik.touched.EmailId && formik.errors.EmailId ? (
            <span style={{ color: "red" }}>{formik.errors.EmailId}</span>
          ) : null}
        </p>
        <button type="submit">Create</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

why Do Hooks get updated 2nd time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Comment: thanx man..got it

Comment: I had tried it but the value which i had set in useEffect() is not getting reflected in another function